# How to call a function in a for loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I would like to call (execute) an m-file (function) in a loop like this:

```
global m, r
m = 2;
for n = 2:10;
  for r1 = 0:n-m;
    r2 = n-m-r1;
    r = [r1,r2];   
    [Call the function here?????????]
  end
end
```

This is the function:

```
function main
  x0 = [-0.5403,0.5471];
  fsolve(@fcn,x0)

function z = fcn(X)
  rand('twister',5409);
  global m, r
  a = rand(m,1);
  for i = 1:m
    sm(i) = 0.0;
    for l = m-i+1:m
      sm(i) = sm(i)+r(l);
    end
    s = 1.0/(i+sm(i));
    g(i) = (a(i))^s;     
  end
  prod = 1.0;
  for k = 1:m
    prod = prod * g(m+1-k);
    u(k) = 1.0-prod;
    x(k) = (sqrt(3)/pi)*log(u(k)/(1-u(k)));
  end
  sum = 0;
  sum1 = 0;
  sum2 = 0;
  for j = 1:m
    sum = sum+(r(j)+2)*(1/(1+exp((-pi/sqrt(3))*((x(j)-X(1))/X(2)))));
    sum1 = sum1+(r(j)+2)*((x(j)-X(1))/X(2))*(1/(1+exp((-pi/sqrt(3))*((x(j)-X(1))/X(2)))));
    sum2 = sum2+(x(j)-X(1))/X(2);
  end
  z(1) = pi/(X(2)*sqrt(3))*(-m+sum);
  z(2) =(-1/X(2))*(m+(pi/sqrt(3))*(sum2-sum1));
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 6):

The functions `main` and `fcn` should be saved in a file called "main.m". You have to make sure this file is either in your current working directory or [somewhere on the MATLAB path](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_env/br5tea6-6.html) (as mentioned in a comment by [Amro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97160/amro)) so that MATLAB can get to it. Since `main` requires no input arguments and has no output arguments, you could then just call it in any one of the following ways:

```
main
main;
main()
main();
```

Comment: Of course, you have to make sure that the file main.m is on the path

Answer (score 3):

If you have a function Main.m

### **Main.m**

```
function out = main(in)
% blah blah blah
```

---

You would call the function

```
in = 2;
out = main(in)
```

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Personnally I would create your function without a main() part.

create a file called 
        fcn.m
with your function fcn in it, make sure it's in your working directory or in your matlab path and then call it inside your loop.

```
addpath(genpath('/the/path/to/your/function/');
global m, r
m = 2;
for n = 2:10;
  for r1 = 0:n-m;
    r2 = n-m-r1;
    r = [r1,r2];   
    z=fcn(r)
  end
end
```